# Nested loop summation in 2D using OpenCL

Tags: c++, opencl, reduction

I have recently started working with OpenCL in C++ and I'm trying to fully understand how to use 2D and 3D NDRange. I'm currently implementing Inverse Distance Weighting in OpenCL, but my problem is general.

Below is the serial function to compute the weights and it consists of a nested loop.

```
void computeWeights(int nGrids, int nPoints, double *distances, double *weightSum, const double p) {

    for (int i = 0; i < nGrids; ++i) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < nPoints; ++j) {
            double weight = 1 / pow(distances[i * nPoints + j], p);
            distances[i * nPoints + j] = weight;
            sum += weight;
        }
        weightSum[i] = sum;
    }
}
```

What I would want is to implement the above function using a 2D NDRange, the first being over nGrids and the second over nPoints. What I don't understand, though, is how to handle the summation of the weights into weightSum[i]. I understand that I may have to use parallel sum reduction, somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dispatching a kernel with a 2D global workspace, OpenCL creates a grid of work-items. Each work-item executes the kernel and gets unique ids in both those dimensions.

```
(x,y)|________________________
     | (0,0) (0,1) (0,2) ...
     | (1,0) (1,1) (1,2)
     | (2,0) (2,1) (2,2)
     | ...
```

The work-items are also divided into groups and get unique ids within those work-groups. E.g. for work-groups of size (2,2):

```
(x,y)|________________________
     | (0,0) (0,1) (0,0) ...
     | (1,0) (1,1) (1,0)
     | (0,0) (0,1) (0,0)
     | ...
```

You can arrange the work-groups, so that each one of them performs a reduction.

Your SDK probably has samples, and a parallel reduction will be one of them.

To get you started, here is a kernel that solves your problem. It's in its simplest form, and works for a single work-group per row.

```
// cl::NDRange global(nPoints, nGrids);
// cl::NDRange local(nPoints, 1);
// cl::Local data(nPoints * sizeof (double));
kernel
void computeWeights(global double *distances, global double *weightSum, local double *data, double p)
{
    uint nPoints = get_global_size(0);

    uint j = get_global_id(0);
    uint i = get_global_id(1);
    uint lX = get_local_id(0);

    double weight = 1.0 / pow(distances[i * nPoints + j], p);

    distances[i * nPoints + j] = weight;

    data[lX] = weight;

    for (uint d = get_local_size(0) >> 1; d > 0; d >>= 1)
    {
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
        if (lX < d)
            data[lX] += data[lX + d];
    }

    if (lX == 0) 
        weightSum[i] = data[0];
}
```

Each row of work-items (i.e. each work-group) computes the weights (and their sum) for `grid i`. Each work-item computes a weight, stores it back to `distances`, and loads it onto local memory. Then each work-group performs a reduction in local memory, and finally the result gets stored in `weightSum`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Reducing the rows helped me understand what is really going on.

I'm working on extending it at the moment, since a too large nPoints isn't possible to create. Having multiple work groups per row is an option, but then I need to synchronize the writing to weightSum[i] and I'm hesitant to use the special implementation of atomic_add for double.

Comment: Synchronization exists only within a work-group. Also atomics work only with integer types (at least for add).
The way to approach this is the following: For starters, load 2 distances (doubles) per work-item, or even better load 2 double2 or double4 per work-item, so that each work-item computes 4 (or 8) weights. Then, if `nPoints` is still too big, you reduce the weights in blocks. You store the sum from each work-group in global memory, and in a second kernel, you reduce these sums as usual.